# Virtual user XXX Logged in while downloading file

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, webclient

I am using WebClient class for downloading files from a given URL .
I am using following function to save it on local server,

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential("my username", "my password");
IWebProxy proxy = HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
wb.Proxy = proxy;
wb.Credentials = creds;
wb.DownloadFile("source url", "C://downloaded.rpt.rsp");
```

but after processing destination file contains

> Virtual user XXX logged in successfully

Comment: Could it be that this is the answer of the server?

Comment: Could it be that you're not tracking the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Did you try to manually download that file via a web-browser (like IE or chrome) and see what it downloads ? If it still gets that, maybe the server is re-directing the URL to somewhere. plz check.

Just for your reference, the minimal code (without auth and proxy) to download a file.

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile("http://www.abc.com/file/song/a.mpeg", "a.mpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 2 step response from the server side. 
Authentication (with cookie) and redirect to the file.

You can see the details when downloading with the browser with a Fiddler on. The browser does a redirect and that won't work when doing Http request.

Try requesting with httpWebRequest and cookie container. And call it again with the authentication cookie.

Comment: Amir - do you have a code sample? I tried HttpWebRequest but had the same result. I also tried Fiddler but all the traffic is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do two steps, 1) login, 2) download file.

Try this:

```
CookieAwareWebClient wb = new CookieAwareWebClient();
string response = wb.DownloadString("source url"); //should say Virtual user XXX Logged in
wb.DownloadFile("source url", "C://downloaded.rpt.rsp");
```

Be sure you are using CookieAwareWebClient:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private readonly CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
```